# Vectorize weighted mean by list of names in each row of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, weighted-average

I have two dataframes. I would like to calculate a weighted mean for each row of my `results` dataframe from the values in my `values` dataframe. Each row of `results` has two columns with lists. Every possible combination of the lists is a row in the `values` dataframe. I am doing this with the code below (two options), which is probably clearer than me trying to explain it. What I would like to know is if and how I can vectorize this (my original results dataframe is very large).

```
library(dplyr)

a = c('a, b, c', 'a, b', 'c') 
f = c('p, q', 'r', 's, t') 
results <- data.frame(a, f)
# > results
# a    f
# 1 a, b, c p, q
# 2    a, b    r
# 3       c s, t

av = c('a','b','c') 
fv = c('p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't')
values <- expand.grid(av, fv)
values$w <- runif(15)
values$x <- runif(15, min=10, max=100)

# > values
# Var1 Var2          w        x
# 1     a    p 0.10710168 62.58004
# 2     b    p 0.89175147 20.26853
# 3     c    p 0.31489520 85.90532
# 4     a    q 0.07263807 89.02293
# 5     b    q 0.87090293 72.17195
# 6     c    q 0.88818599 48.65717
# 7     a    r 0.54076274 39.46479
# 8     b    r 0.08678314 57.99200
# 9     c    r 0.86298554 77.00845
# 10    a    s 0.41778402 23.35626
# 11    b    s 0.70227865 82.76310
# 12    c    s 0.84415123 65.26321
# 13    a    t 0.50651689 75.52230
# 14    b    t 0.37850063 87.41811
# 15    c    t 0.58515251 96.74228

# Option 1 with apply
calc_wa <- function(as, fs){
  as <- unlist(strsplit(as, ", "))
  fs <- unlist(strsplit(fs, ", "))
  valuestokeep <- values %>% filter(Var1 %in% as, Var2 %in% fs)
  wa_res <- weighted.mean(valuestokeep$x, valuestokeep$w)
  return(wa_res)
}

results$res <- apply(results, 1, function(y) calc_wa(y['a'], y['f'])) 

# Option 2 with mutate
calc_wa2 <- function(as, fs){
  as <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(as), ", "))
  fs <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(fs), ", "))
  valuestokeep <- values %>% filter(Var1 %in% as, Var2 %in% fs)
  wa_res <- weighted.mean(valuestokeep$x, valuestokeep$w)
  return(wa_res)
}
results <- results %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(res2= calc_wa2(a, f))
# > results
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
#   # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   a       f       res  res2
# <fct>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 a, b, c p, q   52.3  52.3
# 2 a, b    r      42.0  42.0
# 3 c       s, t   78.2  78.2
```

(I am afraid I am missing some basic command, I also have no idea how to title/tag the question - suggestions welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` instead:

Setup Data (made some slight variations):

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1) # added for reproducability
a = c('a, b, c', 'a, b', 'c')
f = c('p, q', 'r', 's, t')
results <- data.table(a, f) #slight change
# > results
# a    f
# 1 a, b, c p, q
# 2    a, b    r
# 3       c s, t

av = c('a','b','c') 
fv = c('p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't')
values <- expand.grid(av = av, fv = fv) #slight change
values$w <- runif(15)
values$x <- runif(15, min=10, max=100)
```

Code:

```
results[, rowID := 1:.N] # add ID
results_expand <- results[, expand.grid(as = trimws(unlist(strsplit(a, ","))),fs = trimws(unlist(strsplit(f, ","))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), by = .(rowID)] # expand results
# Alternate: results_expand <- results[, CJ(as = trimws(unlist(strsplit(a, ","))),fs = trimws(unlist(strsplit(f, ",")))), by = .(rowID)] # expand results

results_expand <- merge(results_expand, values, by.x = c("as","fs"), by.y = c("av","fv")) # merge to value table
results_expand <- results_expand[, .(wm = weighted.mean(x, w)), by = rowID] # calculate weight

results <- merge(results, results_expand, by = "rowID")

results
   rowID       a    f       wm
1:     1 a, b, c p, q 74.56427
2:     2    a, b    r 45.37445
3:     3       c s, t 35.14175
```

This uses merge and grouping functions in data.table, so should be faster than any looping option.

Comment: there is a problem in your results_expand variable when you do expand.grid, it is as if the grouping was not working and I can't figure out how to fix it (I am not familiar with data.table). But for the procedure you put me on the right track, so I can now do the same thing with dataframes. I will accept your answer (and start using data.table!) if we can fix that. Results with the seed should be 1: 74.56427, 2: 45.37445 and 3: 35.14175

Comment: @esperluette corrected in the above - good catch. strange error with expand.grid using factors instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The same procedure suggested by @Chris but using data.frame instead of data.table

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)

set.seed(1) # added for reproducability

a = c('a, b, c', 'a, b', 'c') 
f = c('p, q', 'r', 's, t') 
results <- data.frame(a, f)

av = c('a','b','c') 
fv = c('p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't')

values <- expand.grid(av=av, fv=fv)
values$w <- runif(15)
values$x <- runif(15, min=10, max=100)

results$ID <- seq.int(nrow(results))

results_expand<- results %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  expand(as=trimws(unlist(strsplit(as.character(a), ","))), fs=trimws(unlist(strsplit(as.character(f), ","))))

results_expand <- merge(results_expand, values, by.x = c("as","fs"), by.y = c("av","fv"))
results_expand <- results_expand %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(wm = weighted.mean(x, w))
results <- merge(results, results_expand, by = "ID")
results <- results  %>%  group_by(ID) %>% select(ID, a, f, wm)
results <- distinct(results)
```